# JPA anotação @Autowired

Tags: jpa

O @Autowired é o mesmo que extends?

Vejamos um pequeno exemplo:

package com.dendetech.services;

import com.dendetech.entity.Participante;
import com.dendetech.repositories.ParticipanteRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ParticipanteService {

```
@Autowired
private ParticipanteRepository participanteRepository;

/*
 * Crud Operations
 */
```

<(Restante omitido).
>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, cada coisa é uma coisa.

Esta anotação está injetando automaticamente uma instancia de `ParticipanteRepository`.

Para que você não precise usar `new ParticipanteRepository()` ou outro método de criação sempre.

Extends é Herança, neste caso o Service herdaria do Repository.

Comment: Na linha:

>"@Autowired
private ParticipanteRepository participanteRepository;"

A variável participanteRepository é quem recebe a instância do objeto da classe ParticipanteRepository?

Outra pergunta, isso significa que sendo o objeto instanciado na classe ParticipanteRepository, posso usá-lo no service através do @Autowired, pois não é possível usar um objeto instanciado em outra parte do código?

Comment: 1 - Sim, neste linha e variável recebe a instância da classe autamticamente. 2 - O objeto será instanciado na classe que for declarado. Neste caso ele está declarado dentro da classe ParticipanteService. Se precisar desta instância em outro local, pode inserir métodos getter públicos para então chamar parrticipanteService.getParticipanteRepository(). Não faz muito sentido usar desta segunda maneira. Em caso de dúvidas poste em outra pergunta.